# Return object with reference to HTTP response stream

Tags: java

I'm using the Apache HTTP client to consume a webservice that returns a file in the response.

I have a method that makes a post request and returns a `CustomServiceResult.java` containing a `byte[]` of the file returned from that request.

I would however prefer that to return an `InputStream` for obvious reasons.

The below code is how I would like to implement it, currently I buffer the `InputStream` and construct the `CustomServiceResult` with that byte array.

The behaviour I get when returning the `InputStream` is that stream closes, which makes total sense but is not ideal.

Is there a common pattern for what I am trying to do?

How can I hold on to that `InputStream` so that the consumer of the `CustomServiceResult` can receive the file?

```
public CustomServiceResult invoke(HttpEntity httpEntity) throws IOException {
    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url + MAKE_SEARCHABLE);
        httppost.setEntity(httpEntity);

        try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost)) {
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode != 200 || resEntity.getContent() == null) {
                throw new CustomServiceException(IOUtils.toString(resEntity.getContent(), "utf-8"),
                        statusCode);
            }

            // resEntity.getContent() is InputStream
            return new CustomServiceResult(resEntity.getContent());
        }
    }
}


public class CustomServiceResult {

    private InputStream objectContent;

    public CustomServiceResult(InputStream objectContent) {
        this.objectContent = objectContent;
    }

    public InputStream getObjectContent() {
        return objectContent;
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

I managed to get this working and understand the behaviour of my try with resources statement was ultimately closing the connection.

This is the approach I took to get the outcome I was after.

```
public CustomServiceResult invoke(HttpEntity httpEntity) throws IOException {
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    httppost.setEntity(httpEntity);

    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode != 200 || resEntity.getContent() == null) {
        throw new CustomServiceException(IOUtils.toString(resEntity.getContent(), "utf-8"),
                statusCode);
    }

    return new CustomServiceResult(resEntity.getContent());
}
```

This, by the way is how I have been testing:

```
@Test
public void testCreateSearchablePdf() throws Exception {
    CustomServiceResult result = client.downloadFile();
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("blabla.pdf");
    IOUtils.copy(result.getObjectContent(), os);
}
```

My remaining questions:

1. Is the updated implementation safe, does something automatically release the connection?
2. What side effects could I expect?

Answer (score -3):

You can use a `ByteArrayInputStream` to transform the byte array back to a Inputstream.

Comment: This doesn't solve my actual problem. I want to avoid buffering the content in a byte array as that won't scale with large files

Comment: The stream closes because the Apache HTTP Client wants to close the connection to the server. If you want to keep less data in your RAM you should concider to write the data to a file.